# We should change the name of our community to 'Linux & Unix'

Tags: discussion, site-name

First, because it is alphabetically correct.
Second, most of the questions are related to Linux, not Unix

Comment: Unix begat Linux... It is customary to refer to the progenitor before the progeny.

Comment: this isn't going to happen

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unix and Linux - Linux and Unix - I think jasonwryan is right. We should stick to the historical order - it even sounds better.